# QtWebkit: how to send an exception from Qt to the JavaScript context?

Tags: qt, webkit, qtwebkit

I have a simple Qt 4.7 application that uses QtWebKit to display a HTML/JavaScript page. Using `addToJavaScriptWindowObject()` a few C++ functions are provided to the JavaScript environment.

Is there a way to raise an exception *in the JavaScript context* in certain situations when such a function is called from JavaScript?

- Throwing a C++ exception, like `throw 123;`, simply crashes the Qt application
- Using `evaluateJavaScript("throw new Error('whatever');")` I can throw an exception but apparently it is not being passed to the calling JavaScript context (i.e. just the `eval()` code itself is being aborted)

Looking at the source code I see methods like `setException()` and similar but apparently I need a JSContext or some other reference to the calling JavaScript context, but I have no clue how to get it (there is no such thing in `QWebFrame` although WebKit itself or `QWebFramePrivate` seem to have such a reference.

My final goal is that a **JavaScript** code like

```
try {
  specialBrowserObject.someFunction();
} catch (e) {
  document.write("Exception: "+e.message);
}
```

shows the exception created in C++ (`specialBrowserObject` being the object exposed via `addToJavaScriptWindowObject()`).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I've been able to tell, it isn't possible to throw an exception from C++ to be caught in JavaScript.  I can suggest a few workarounds but these may, or may not, be suitable solutions for you.  I realise that neither is the perfect solution you were hoping for.

1) Use a `Q_PROPERTY` so that the C++ code can set a value if it wants to cause an exception on return to the JavaScript.  The JavaScript would have to check the value to see if an exception is required upon return from the C++ function and then throw one manually.

2) Along the same lines, but slightly neater in my opinion, would be to use a `Q_INVOKABLE` function that returns a QString to your JavaScript.  If the string isn't empty, throw an exception from JavaScript.

The function would be defined in the header file as -

```
Q_INVOKABLE QString someFunction( int divisor );
```

The function would be something along these lines in the main cpp file -

```
QString className::someFunction( int divisor ) {
  // Main body of function doing various things
  ...
  ...
  // Do we need to throw an exception?
  if( divisor == 0 )
    return "Divide by zero";
  ...
  ...
  // Function has succeeded so no need to throw an exception
  return "";
}
```

The JavaScript would look something like this -

```
try {
  retVal = specialBrowserObject.someFunction( divisor );
  if( retVal != "" )
    throw new Error( retVal );
} catch (e) {
  document.write("Exception: "+e.message);
}
```

I hope this is of some help.

Comment: I could write a JavaScript wrapper that checks the function return value, so the second solution would be an option. However, the function itself should return a value so I need a different way to pass the exception info (for example, one function should read and return a file, see http://pastebin.com/4CL5ezMr). As for the `Q_PROPERTY` solution: would this be a string property that can be accessed from both C++ and JavaScript?

Comment: You need to define the Q_PROPERTY, the C++ variable and a helper function to read the variable. `Q_PROPERTY( QString exceptionString READ GetException )`, `QString exception;` and `QString GetException( ) const { return exception; }`.  You can set the exception string in C++ and access it using specialBrowserObject.exceptionString from JavaScript

Comment: Thanks. This solution works. I wrote a wrapper that passes the exception in a similar way and works fine.